# In the Vsix plug-in, how to query Oracle "Long" type data using the ODP.NET driver

Tags: oracle, odp.net, vsix

In the Vsix plug-in, using the ODP.NET driver, Oracle "Long" type data cannot be queried. I tried setting "InitialLONGFetchSize=-1" in the service instance, but the property is read-only and cannot be modified.

My Code:

```
//...
var command = _connection.GetRequiredService<IVsDataCommand>();
var vsReader = command.Execute(sql, DataCommandType.Text, null, 120); 
//...
```

How to query Long type data through the services provided by VS?
Thanks in advance.